# array_udiff not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays of objects.
What I want to do it to find differences based on a certain attribute of the object **IF** another attribute is equal.

A cut down version of my code is ([viewable here](http://codepad.org/4YSs21wW));

```
<?php
echo "Testing\n";

$aud1 = new stdClass();
$aud1->code = 'Z1';
$aud1->sub_list = '2, 3, 1';

$aud2 = new stdClass();
$aud2->code = 'Z2';
$aud2->sub_list = '2, 4, 1';

$aud3 = new stdClass();
$aud3->code = 'Z3';
$aud3->sub_list = '2, 3, 1';

$aud4 = new stdClass();
$aud4->code = 'Z2';
$aud4->sub_list = '2, 3, 1';

$array1 = array(
    $aud1,
    $aud3
);

$array2 = array(
    $aud2,
    $aud4
);

echo "\nsample A\n";
print_r($array1);

echo "\nsample B\n";
print_r($array2);

$arrdiff1 = array_values(array_udiff($array1, $array2, 'myDiff'));
echo "\nIn A but not in B\n";
print_r($arrdiff1);


$arrdiff2 = array_values(array_udiff($array2, $array1, 'myDiff'));
echo "\nIn B but not in A\n";
print_r($arrdiff2);



function myDiff($a, $b) {
    if ($a->code == $b->code) {
        return strcmp($a->sub_list, $b->sub_list);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

?>
```

I am expecting to see a difference where A is **Z2 2,3,1** and B is **Z2 2,4,1**

Why is this not showing?

**UPDATE**
As *@pilsetnieks* says, I got my elements mixed up - not enough coffee.

BUt I am confused as to why doesn't show up in $arraDiff1.
[Updated code here](http://codepad.org/ynajhCP8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison function compares the `code` property first and it's either `Z1` or `Z3` for the `$array1` and `Z2` for the `$array2`. Because of that, your function always goes to `return 0`

Comment: -1 for me not looking properly, more caffeine required

Comment: why isn't Z1 2,4,1 not appearing in $arraydiff1?

Comment: `$arraydiff1` is a comparison of the same arrays, just in a different order. The `code` properties of the contained objects are still different and it still leads to the `else` clause.

Comment: But the documentation says "Returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are not present in any of the other arguments.", that is why I am doing the same in reverse. So I can see what in A but not in B and vice versa

Comment: The problem is with the data in your objects and your comparison function. As it is now, in all of the cases the comparison function (`myDiff`) returns 0 for any comparison, thus indicating that the values aren't different.