# array_push & array_udiff with custom class objects

Tags: php, arrays, class, dynamic-arrays

I am pushing class objects onto two different arrays an then want to take the different of these arrays. However, when I use array push with array_udiff I cannot get array_udiff to output anything other than null. Here's the barebones of the code.

Class definition:

```
class follower
{
    public $friend;
    public $newposts;

    }
```

Data assignment: for loop containing:

```
        $holder = new follower();
....put data in $holder....
        array_push($object_array1, $holder);
```

second for loop doing the same thing...

```
       $holder = new follower();
....put data in $holder....
    array_push($object_array2, $holder);
```

Function to compare objects in the object arrays:

```
function compare_followers($f1, $f2)
{
    $s1 = $f1->friend;
    $s2 = $f2->friend;
    return strcmp($s1, $s2);
}
```

And finally unsuccessful attempt to compare these two arrays (the arrays look as they should, arrays of follower objects)

```
$object_array = array_udiff($object_array2, $object_array1, 'compare_followers');
```

$object_array is null. In addition to the code above, I tried playing around with the comparison function - making it a static function within the class or declaring it as an unnamed function in the array_udiff call, but neither of those things worked.

If I apply compare_followers to individual class members, that works fine. Similarly, if I push the following object onto my $object_array1 and $object_array2  the array_udiff works fine:

```
    $holderA = array(
            'friend' =>$holder->friend,
            'newposts' => $holder->newposts
            );

        array_push($object_array2, $holder); (and same for $object_array1)

$object_array = array_udiff($object_array2, $object_array1, 'compare_followers');
```

The problem with this latter, working apprpoach is that it gives a dictionary of objects rather than an array of objects - I need an array.

Here are some of the stackoverflow questions that are relevant but don't address this: [array_udiff not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694468/array-udiff-not-working-as-expected), [How does array_udiff() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271708/how-does-array-udiff-work), [array intersect for object array php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834607/array-intersect-for-object-array-php/26398810#26398810).
Here's the documentation for this class (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your `compare_followers` function ? Try to output the `$f1`, `$f2`, `$s1`, `$s2` and the output of strcmp($s1, $s2) and make sure that it returns a value that make sense to `array_udiff`

Comment: Hi Nico, Yes I've done this. I can compare elements of the array and also individual follower objects, and the output is as it should be. Also, to simplify things, I also tried to make compare_followers always return 1 or always return 0, but the output of array_udiff was always still nil with my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Careful of what the arrays actually contain.

```
<?php

class follower {
    public $friend;
    public $newposts;

    public function __construct($friend, $newpost) {
        $this->friend = $friend;
        $this->newposts = $newpost;
    }
}

$object_array1 = array();
$holder = new follower('me', 'first');
array_push($object_array1, $holder);

$object_array2 = array();
$holder = new follower('you', 'second');
array_push($object_array2, $holder);

function compare_followers($f1, $f2) {
    $s1 = $f1->friend;
    $s2 = $f2->friend;
    return strcmp($s1, $s2);
}

$object_array = array_udiff($object_array2, $object_array1, 'compare_followers');

var_dump($object_array);
```

Comment: Thanks! So it's not null anymore, but the format still isn't quite the same as the original arrays when json encoded. Here's the result of the array push - an array of objects/dictionaries:[{"friend":"brooklynsage","newposts":null},{"friend":"jackR","newposts":null},...etc whereas after the array_udiff with your syntax, I still have a dictionary of dictionaries/objects:{"12":{"friend":"jonjon","newposts":null},"14":{"friend":"laylaohio2","newposts":null}}...

Comment: json_encode returns array [] only when keys are int and in order. That means that array(0=>'val',1=>'val') will give array. but array(0=>'val',2=>'val') won't. Assoc array won't give array neither